# Queueing and Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, queue, isolatedstorage

I have a small application that queues some requests and pulls them off the stack.

However, the application on the server servicing the queue may at any point fail and I need to be able to rebuild the queue when the application starts up again.  This cannot be handled in a database as the database reads and writes are slow in this environment hence the queueing to at least give the user the perception of speed.

Does anyone know of a library that will enable me to store the queue in isolated storage.  It would need to be able to maintain the queue at any time during `enqueue` and `dequeue` opperations.

The only thing I have tried thus far is to serialize the queue items as they are pushed onto the queue but now am stuck with the pull as to the approach which is why I was hoping there might be a library.

**edit**

Is the answer to simply reserialise the entire queue everytime there is a `enqueue` and `dequeue`?

And how would I "`peek`" at the entire queue to get all the items in the first place?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". It just makes the title ugly, and the tags already cover that.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, yep, fair enough.  Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 1):

My first advise would be to use [ActiveMQ](http://www.firatatagun.com/activemq-installation-on-centos/2011/11/02/) or [RabbitMQ](http://www.firatatagun.com/rabbitmq/2011/11/24/), both uses persistence, with fail over, they are very easy to pick up. ActiveMQ has its own database as well as you can plugin your own database.

If you dont want to use database, ActiveMQ still persist the data at temp files and provides you reliability.

If you dont want to use these products, you can use a [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx), and whenever you enqueue, asynchronously write that to a isolated storage, then you ll have to maintain it when you dequeue.
Also, you might consider seperate app domain for this part so if your main app goes down, you can still have your queue running.

I believe you will have more cases to cover this is just intuitive.

Edit:

Serializing the entire queue would slow you down a lot as serialization is expensive.
Peek is implemented as a feature of every queue.

Comment: Yes but "peek" only looks at the last item in the queue which is a shame.  As for the two products you mentioned i think RabbitMQ looks like a likely candidate.  Will investigate. +1 for that thanks.

Comment: yeah peek only looks at the last item. if you want to look all of them you will have to get all of them, put them on a stack and then store it back to queue.

Comment: ActiveMQ is also a very good product. I have used it and been happy. I wouldnt recomend MSMQ if your consumer wont be as fast as producers.

Comment: yeah but ActiveMQ is buywear and these people are, um, tight!

Comment: Hmm... ActiveMQ is open source software... http://activemq.apache.org/.  It's java-based, but I've used it with great success from .NET.

Comment: When you don't want an in memory queue and you don't want to install extra products and you are on a windows platform use a transactional [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx). This is a standard component on windows.